# How to list animals by customer id using springboot

Tags: spring-boot, crud

I have two entities Customer and Animal, and I need to list the animals of a given customer, the animal entity receives the id of the customer I would like to list all the animals that have this id.

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "customerId", nullable = false)
private Customer customer;
```

Comment: What does your service and / or repository look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spring Data JPA dependency which will make the task easy for you.
Add this dependency in your pom file:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Assuming your Animal class looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Animal {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
    private Customer customer;
    
    //setters and getters
}
```

your repository class will look like this:

```
public interface AnimalRepository extends CrudRepository<Animal, Long> {
    
    List<Animal> findByCustomer(Customer customer);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you should have an endpoint that receives the `customerId`.

That controller will call a service method, that receives the `customerId` and with that info call a repository method named `findByCustomer` (or something similar), which is the one that queries the database for the info.
The select will be something like:

```
select * from animals a where a.customerId = customerId
```

I recommend you to read about Spring Data JPA which is the tool that use Spring to make that db queries and repository implementation easier.